# How do I insert this data into postgresql with python?

Tags: python, postgresql, parameter-passing, sql-injection, psycopg2

In the following codes,I want insert `authors` by locating `link`.

```
self.cur.execute("""
    UPDATE articles 
    SET authors = %s 
    WHERE link = %s returning id;
""" % (authors, link))
ret_id = self.cur.fetchone()
```

And two problems are encountered:

1. Some names are not regular like this:

   ```
   LINE 1: UPDATE articles SET authors = Francesco D'Angelo,  Roberto T...
   ```
2. When author names are no problem:

   ```
   """UPDATE articles SET authors = %s WHERE link = %s returning id;""" % (authors, link))
   psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ":"
   LINE 1: ...DATE articles SET authors = test WHERE link = http://www.wor...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Don't format your strings with `%` when you are using SQL, let the driver do the proper escaping:

```
self.cur.execute(
    """UPDATE articles SET authors = %s WHERE link = %s returning id;""", (authors, link))
```

Notice I passed the data as the second argument, `execute` will take care of escaping the data properly.